# Keras Input shape of a pretrained model not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to use transfer learning in Keras. I have trained a model for a different task, but now I want to use it for a similar task, but the input and output shapes are different. 
I loaded the trained model using `load_model`. My original model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(28,28,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPool2D(padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPool2D(padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPool2D(padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
rmsdrp = optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.001, epsilon=1e-08)

model.compile( loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
               optimizer = rmsdrp, 
               metrics=['accuracy']
             )
```

Then, for output I did the following:

```
    model.pop()
    model.add(Dense(3*168,activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Reshape((3,168)))
```

This is working. For input, I did this:

```
model.layers[0] = Input(shape=(137,236))
```

But when I printout the model summary, it still gives the previous input shape of the model. What am I doing wrong? How else should I change the input shape? This is the model summary in the end:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        832       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        25632     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 28, 28, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 28, 28, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 128)       102528    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 14, 14, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 64)          131136    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 64)          65600     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 7, 7, 64)          256       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               262400    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 504)               129528    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 3, 168)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 595,706
Trainable params: 595,258
Non-trainable params: 448
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You should also give the whole code with the summary/load/save

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz there is not much other code. just `load_model("filename")` to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the use of `Input(shape=(137,236))` which is usually used for the functional model, not the sequential. You can change the input layer by essentially changing the model:

```py
input = Input(shape=(137,236))
x = model.layers[1](input) #assuming you are ignoring the first conv layer as implied in your code
for layer in model.layers[2:]:
    x = layer(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
model.compile(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Edit:

To make sure the weights do not get, you need to add a for loop to set them to un-trainable.

```py
for layer in model.layers[1:-2]:
    layer.trainable=False
```

Comment: will the weights be retained? Also I dont want to ignore the first conv layer.

Comment: they should, but you should also set the layers to non-trainable to make sure the weights don't change when you retrain.

Comment: I am getting this error `Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_1: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1024 but got shape (None, 34560)`

Comment: This is an issue with the input/output dimensions of the layers; as the Conv layers change the shape of your tensor there is no guarantee the change in Input shape will produce what dense_1 is expecting down the line. you need to check the shapes of batches along the line and see why the shapes are incompatible

Comment: I think it's because the conv layers have same padding, so the output on flatten when 137,236,1 input is 34560 while it was 1024 when using 28,28,1 image. so what should I do?

Comment: You could try replace all the fully connected layers after the flatten one, which is usually the best practice.
While in the debugging phase, try to create one model with the same input shape as the original model, but using the transfer learning code (to ensure the problem comes from that).

Comment: yes, it does work when 28,28,1 is passed to the Input layer in the code. So, I need to add the Dense layers later, just copy the Conv layers from the trained?

Comment: Correct! you need to pop the last 4 layers instead of just one and add new ones with different input/output dimensions.